# How do I chance 1 option selected text in vueforms multi select

Tags: vue.js

Here is the image of the current status of the dropdown-

[image]

```
<Multiselect
  v-model="filter.organization"
  :options="Object.values(organizations)"
  placeholder="ORGANISATION"
  :searchable="true"
  mode="multiple"
  :close-on-select="false"
  :clear-on-select="false"
/>
```

I need to change that `1 option selected` to a placeholder text or a manual text.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by using `slot`.

```
<multiselect
  v-model="value"
  :options="options"
  :multiple="true"
  :close-on-select="false"
  :clear-on-select="false"
  :preserve-search="true"
  placeholder="Pick some"
  label="name"
  track-by="name"
  :preselect-first="true"
  >
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }">
    <span
      class="multiselect__single"
      v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen"
      >
    Custom placeholder
    </span>
  </template>
</multiselect>
```